# How to download a file in Android

Tags: android, httprequest

**What i have:**

1. I have uploaded a .json file to the Dropbox of my account  I have
   made it public

**What i am trying to do:**

1. I want to download the file to my `RAW folder` of my android project
2. I am familiar with `AsyncTask` and `HttpClient` but what
   methodology(steps) should I follow to download the file?

***I tried searching for a similar question in stackoverflow but couldn't find one so posting a question myself***

Comment: What do you mean by your "`RAW folder`"? You want to download a file and then put it inside your APK? Just download it to your apps files dir.

Comment: @JaredRummler ....... RAW folder is a folder i had created in my project for example ...... It can be assets folder too ... i just want to know to process to perform the download from dropbox :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot download a file into "assets" or "/res/raw". Those get compiled into your APK.

You can download the file to your apps internal data directories. See [Saving Files | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html).

There are plenty of examples and libraries to help you with the download. The following is a static factory method you could use in your project:

```
public static void download(String url, File file) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    URLConnection ucon = new URL(url).openConnection();
    HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ucon;
    int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(ucon.getInputStream());
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
        fos.close();
        bis.close();
    }
}
```

Then, to download a file from Dropbox:

```
String url = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27262221/test.txt";
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "test.txt");
try {
    download(url, file);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO handle error
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO handle error
}
```

Please note that the above code should be run from a background thread or you will get a [`NetworkOnMainThreadException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html).

You will also need to declare the following permission in your AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

---

You can find some helpful libraries here: https://android-arsenal.com/free

I personally recommend [http-request](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request). You could download your dropbox file with HttpRequest like this:

```
HttpRequest.get("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27262221/test.txt").receive(
    new File(getFilesDir(), "test.txt"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice Explanation ........ one more question ..... we can do the above process without using login credentials from dropbox ? .... just if i have the location link ...is it sufficient ?

Comment: You don't need to login to download a public file on DropBox. I haven't used it in a production build though (not sure if traffic matters with DropBox). If you don't have a server I would recommend hosting the JSON file on Github.

Comment: Thanks :) .... yes i don't have a server ...... if i host it on github ....... is the processs same as you have described above ? .... (Just for my knowledge)

Comment: Yep, just use the "raw" link.